One-signal satellites data in RTCM messages
I can't understand one thing about GNSS measurements in RTCM messages. I have a base station and it broadcasts a stream of RTCM messages. I take one message of type 1074 from this stream, that is, GPS measurements. and I see the DF396 field there - the cells mask. I parse this field and see, for example, such a table (this is a real example):
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]

at the same time, I know from DF394 that the first of the visible satellites is PRN02, the second is PRN13. Both of these satellites are Block IIR. And there are three more such visible satellites there. And Block IIR supports only one signal: L1 C/A. But in my RTCM message there are measurement data for two signals from these satellites. And I cannot understand: what kind of information is this? Should I ignore it? Or does Block IIR works with L2?

The RTCM v3.x cell mask is a table with n_sig rows and n_sat columns where n_sig is the number of signals and n_sat is the number of satellites included in the stream. By looking at the signal mask (DF395) one can understand what signals are included in the stream. In your case, you shall then be able to understand what the second measurement reported for the first satellite in view (i.e., PRN02) really is.

You are correct, of course DF395 is informative. In my particular case DF395 says that the message contains measurements for L1 C/A, L2, L2C(L), L5. So, if for example there are four ones in one column of DF396 - then the message contains measurements for all four signals for a corresponding satellite. Which is Ok since there are four ones in the three columns all of which represent III or IIF satellites in my message. But the first column, which contains two ones, corresponds to the PRN02 - which, since it is IIR satellite, does not support L2 signal.
Or do I miss something here?

As far as I know, IIR satellites also support signals on L2 frequency. You can check the following links for reference: Wikipedia, in section "Satellite frequencies" or GPS Gov in section "Current and Future Satellite Generations", or in Navipedia

But according to your second link, IIR (not IIR-M) does support only L1. And PRN02 is IIR without M, see here (PRN status by satellite block).
(Thank you for your attention and time by the way. I have not enough reputation to upvote, so just thank you)

@user3711, I am glad if I can help :). My second link shows that IIR supports C/A code on L1 but P code is supported for L1 and L2. So this would mean that for PRN02 you will likely have L1C/A and L2P, but will not have L2C and L5. This would match with the signal mask that you posted!
